# need of loopback route in every host's routing table

Tags: linux, networking, routing

it is always said that every host's routing table must have a entry for loop back route as shown below:

```
Destination     Gateway        Flags  Ref    Use   Interface 
-----------    -----------     -----  ----  -----  --------- 
127.0.0.1      127.0.0.1       UH      1      298      lo0
```

My question is why we need to make such an entry in the routing table even if our loop back interface working well without this.

working well here i mean that i can ping on it and even if i am configuring a http server on my machine and trying to test it with localhost, it is also working well.

note:- i am asking this question in regard of Linux OS.

Comment: If it works without the entry, then clearly, its not required.  So whom ever said it was required is clearly wrong.

Comment: Linux has a implicit routes for its local interfaces - loopback host is 127.0.0.1, with a /8 netmask, so 127.0.0.2 will (correctly) go to that interface as well, even if `netstat -r` doesn't show it. Probably whoever told you this has cargo-culted the "knowledge" from some ancient place that no longer exists - there's all sorts of misinformation about networks out there that hasn't been true for 20 years or more.